# Retrofit custom converter factory for list type

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have two different calls to an api which return different pojos -

```
Call<Verified> verify();

Verified json
-------------
{
  "username":
  "avatar_url":
  "site":
  ...
}
```

---

```
Call<ApiResponse> callapi();

ApiResponse json
----------------
{
  "version":
  "title":
  "url":
  "_meta": {
    "about":
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "id":
      "url":
      "date":
      ...
    },
    ...
  ] 
}
```

I want only the inner `items` data so I wrote a custom Retrofit envelope converter for it -

```
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                                                            Retrofit retrofit) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ApiResponse> delegate =
                retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, ApiResponse.class, annotations);
        return value -> {
            ApiResponse envelope = delegate.convert(value);
            return envelope.items;
        };
    }
```

So now I can call using `Call<List<Item>> callapi();`.

But for some reason, the `verify()` call does not work. The response in that case is always null. If I add this check -

```
if (type != ApiResponse.class)
    return null;
```

in the converter then it works but strangely causes `callapi()` to fail throwing the error `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`. Why is the converter not working? Also, shouldn't Retrofit fall back on the next converter in case a converter can't parse a json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `type` in the parameters is the type of the `Call`, the correct check to skip non-`List<Item>` cases was -

```
if (!type.equals(Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Item.class)))
    return null;
```

This allows the next converter to process the response if the type of the call is not `List<Item>`.

Comment: what is `Types`?